# How can I find the change of coordinates matrix of a subspace given two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

If I have a subspace, *S* = {$p(x)$ $\in$ $P_2(R)$ | $p(1) = 0$} of $P_2(R)$.

$A$ = {$-1 + x, -1 + x^2$ } and $B$ = {$1 + x - 2x^2$ , $3 - 4x + x^2$ } are both bases for *S*.

What is the change of the coordinates matrices from $B$ to $A$ and $A$ to $B$?

i.e
$_AP_B$ and what is $_BP_A$

---

I started to find the A-coordinates of vectors in B by doing

$1 + x - 2x^2$ = $c_1$($-1 + x)$ + $c_2$($-1 + x^2$) = 
$ -1 (c_1 +c_2) + (c_1) x + (c_2) x^2$

$3 - 4x + x^2$ = $d_1$($-1 + x)$ + $d_2$($-1 + x^2$) =
$ -1 (d_1 +d_2) + (d_1) x + (d_2) x^2$

; but was unsure how to continue and form this into an augmented matrix

---

ETA

So my augmented matrix will end up being:

$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
1 & 1 & -2 & 1 & -2  \\
3 & -4 & 1 & 1 & -4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

for the A-coordinates of vectors in B?

Please edit the matrix to correct it if/because it is wrong.

Comment: If a polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$ is equal to another $a'+b' x+c x^2$, then $a=a'$, $b=b'$, and $c=c'$. In this case, notice that we must have $c_2=-2$ and $c_1=1$, and also $d_2=1$ and $d_1=-4$ so that the $x^2$ and $x$ terms have the same coefficients in both equations. That's your matrix.
BTW: Another characterization of $S$ is $S={p(x) | p(x)=a+bx+cx^2, a+b+c=0 }$ So a+b=-c, so actually $S={p(x) | p(x)=a+bx-(a+b) x^2}$. If  you write polynomials in $S$ as vectors $(a,b,a+b)$, then you see clearly $dim(S)=2$ and you can write A'={(-1,1), (-1,0)} and B'={(1,1),(3,-4)}.

Comment: (continuing) Finding the change of coordinates basis from $A'$ to $B'$ solves your problem too.

Comment: @facuq So I have tried creating a matrix with the following coefficients, but I don't think it will work to try and find A' and B'

Comment: I find this question ambiguous every time someone posts it here. Are you supposed to find a $3\times 3$ matrix, in which case the solution is not unique, or are you supposed to treat $S$ as a two-dimensional space in its own right, and so find a $2\times 2$ matrix? (See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1688392/265466 for a similar question.)

Comment: I believe its the latter. dimension of the subspace is less than or equal to the dimension of the vector space its in. a plane in R3 is a subspace of R3, but a basis for the plane can have only two vectors in it.
However, for this question I seem to have the possible coefficients figured out but can't seem to make it into a matrix that works...